# How do I copy list item metadata (version history) from one list to another list using C#

Tags: 2007, list

When copying list items from one list to another list, how can I access and copy the item's version history?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an [article](http://vspug.com/dez/2007/11/30/moving-copying-documents-between-libraries-with-metadata-including-version-history/) awhile back that may help...it covers moving documents from one library to another while preserving metadata and version history.

Comment: Can that solution also be used to copy list items and versions as well?